# Взамодействие с камерой в SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Было раньше приложение еще на Symbian, которое взамодействовало с камерой и на экрне можно было убивать вирусы.
Вопрос в том, что можно ли использовать камеру в iOS в реальном времени и передавать пользователю модифицированную картинку, так скажем, "налету"? Если да, то как это можно сделать?

Comment: можно. загуглите ios augmented reality там туториалов тыщи. типа такого http://www.raywenderlich.com/40870/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-marker-tracking

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, спасибо! То, что нужно!

Comment: с позволения перенесу комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы хотите сделать называется augmented reality. Очень много примеров можно найти на гугле. [Например тут](http://www.raywenderlich.com/40870/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-marker-tracking).